AZ Pipeline: PS on Target Machines is unable to create a connection to the source SQL Server instance/database, while the same is successful locally
PowerShell script: "Function: Copy-SQLTable" Connects to a source SQL Server instance and database and altera the data.

This script works as expected when running locally
The same script is successful on another Windows SQL server in another region of the application.

The Issue is only when running the same script from the Azure pipelines on a specific environment, The target Machines task is unable to create a connection to the source SQL Server instance and database.
Environment:
Agent: Windows
Remote server: Windows
I don't see enough logs to look at the specific issue.
I need help with identifying the difference between the two environments.
I tried comparing working and non-working environments, but I had no luck.
I'm expecting help in identifying the difference between two environments and make the PowerShell script establish the connection between Azure Agent and Windows server/

The question was tagged with mysql, but you kept writing sql server, which is a different database product. Which one do you use? Also, it is unclear where your source and target databases are hosted and where your data pipeline is run. You also did not share the exact error message with us. At the moment, it is unclear if this question is about programming or sw development at all. It may be more about network and database configurations.

Hi there, you mentioned the Copy-SQLTable command worked locally but didn't work on the Windows agent from your pipeline environment, right? May I ask if this pipeline agent machine in your environment was the same local machine where you ran the command? Or say, did you configure this local machine as a self-hosted agent resource in your environment to run your pipeline? Or the target machine that your pipeline run PS script on was your local machine?

If you run Copy-SQLTable command directly from the target machine without using pipeline, will the connection work?
